# loop through datatable to create a string that looks like this

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to loop through my datatable column called SDESCR and created a string that looks like this.

```
Dim labels As String() = {"North", "South", "East", "West", "Up", "Down"}
```

this is what i am trying and it is not working

```
Dim labels As String() 
For Each row As DataRow In tablegraph.Rows
            labels = labels " ' " + row.Item("SDESCR") + " ',"
        Next row
```

**THANK YOU FOR THE HELP, I WILL TEST THEM TOMORROW AND SEE WHICH WORKS BEST AND MARK ONE CORRECT.**

Comment: `labels` is not a string but a String-Array.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"?  Are you getting an error?  Do you get output but the wrong output?  Also, I assume this is a type, but you have `labels " ' "` where I assume you mean `labels + " ' "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this instead

```
Dim labels As String()
Dim labelsList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
For Each row As DataRow In tablegraph.Rows
  labelsList.Add(row.Item("SDESCR"))
Next

labels = labelsList.ToArray()
```

If you need it to be a comma delimited list instead you can just do

```
Dim commaLabels As String = String.Join(labels, ",")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need them stored in an array, then you can add them to a list and then call the ToArray() method on the list:

```
    Dim labelList As New List(Of String)
    For Each row As DataRow In tablegraph.Rows
        labelList.Add(row.Item("SDESCR"))
    Next row

    Dim labels As String() = labelList.ToArray()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a String-Array instead of a String, this works:

```
Dim labels(tablegraph.Rows.Count - 1) As String
For i As Int32 = 0 To tablegraph.Rows.Count - 1
    labels(i) = tablegraph(i)("SDESCR").ToString
Next
```

If you want them separated with a comma, you can use a StringBuilder to append:

```
 Dim labels As New System.Text.StringBuilder
 For i As Int32 = 0 To tablegraph.Rows.Count - 1
     labels.Append(" ' ").Append(tablegraph(i)("SDESCR").ToString).Append(" ',")
 Next
 If labels.Length <> 0 Then labels.Length -= 1 'remove last comma'
 Dim labelString As String = labels.ToString
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a string, use this (string builder is best due to memory management issues with constant string declaration.

```
Dim labels As New StringBuilder()
For Each row As DataRow In tablegraph.Rows
            labels.Append(" ' " + row.Item("SDESCR") + " ',")
        Next row
```

Then when you need the string, use labels.ToString()

If you want an array, use this...

```
Dim labels As New List(Of String)()
For Each row As DataRow In tablegraph.Rows
            labels.Add(row.Item("SDESCR"))
        Next row
```

Then when you need the array, use labels.ToArray()

The main reason your above code is failing is that you are declaring an Array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to do this; here is an approach using LINQ

```
Dim labels As String() = (From myRow In tablegraph _
                          Select CType(myRow.Item("SDESCR"), String)).ToArray
```

- It's worth nothing that this will fail for NULL/NOTHING values of "SDESCR".

If you just want a single comma-separated values you can do this:

```
Dim sOutput = String.Join(",", (From myRow In tablegraph _
                                Select CType(myRow.Item("SDESCR"), String)).ToArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
labels = labels " ' " + row.Item("SDESCR") + " ',"
               ^
```

Plus sign missing?
Also, when you do this you'll be left with an extra `,` at the end of your string. So you'll want to strip that off.

Comment: if i add a plus sign i get an error its Error 5 Operator '+' is not defined for types '1-dimensional array of String' and 'String'.